# Why is the where function of Cloud Firestore not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, discord.js

I am trying to make a warn system with discord.js and I am using Cloud Firestore for the database. I am trying to make a system where when a admin sends a command, it uses the `where` function to find all documents with the userid of the user the admin is trying to warn.

Here is the code that I am using for the command:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.author.id != client.user.id) {
    if (msg.content.startsWith(";getwarns")) {
      let user = msg.mentions.users.first()
      if (user) {
        let member = msg.guild.member(user)
        if (member) {
         let warnref = db.collection('Warns')
         console.log(user.id)
         let snapshot =  warnref.where('UserId', '==', user.id).get()
         console.log(snapshot)
        }
      } else {
       msg.reply("You have not mentioned anybody")
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Could you provide the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that Firebase's `.get()` method is asynchronous. When you use `where()` to query for all of the documents that meet a certain condition, and use `get()` to retrieve the results, you need to `await` for the results. Also make sure that you add `async` in front of the message handler:

```js
client.on('message', async (msg) => {
  if (msg.author.id != client.user.id) {
    if (msg.content.startsWith(";getwarns")) {
      let user = msg.mentions.users.first()
      if (user) {
        let member = msg.guild.member(user)
        if (member) {
         let warnref = db.collection('Warns')
         console.log(user.id)
         let snapshot =  await warnref.where('UserId', '==', user.id).get()
         console.log(snapshot)
        }
      } else {
       msg.reply("You have not mentioned anybody")
      }
    }
  }
})
```